# combination of normal and cartopy subplots within the same figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, geospatial, cartopy

I want a plot with two subplots, one larger with a map and second smaller with a scatter plot. I am using cartopy for plotting map. I determine the fraction of height by using gridspec_kw. However, due to projection constraints, it also affects the width.[image: This is what i get].

This is what I get.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy as ccrs
fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,1,subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.crs.PlateCarree()),gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [4, 1]})
```

One possible solution would be to use subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.crs.PlateCarree() only for the upper panel. But i am not able to figure out how do this. There are ways which recommend add_subplot, but that is very manual and i don't like this. Is is possible to do with plt.subplots()?

[image: This is what I want]
This is what I want.

Comment: No you cannot do this with subplots.

Comment: Have you tried a `(2,3)` shaped figure? with `(0,0)` position and `colspan=3` for cartopy's ax, and `(1,1)`  position for scatter plot. [matplotlib grispec and others placement managers](https://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/users/gridspec.html)

Answer (score 11):

my suggestion would be to use `gridspec` to control the subplots size and `fig.add_subplot` instead of `plt.subplots`. That way you could specify the Cartopy projection only to the first subplot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

fig = plt.figure()
gs = fig.add_gridspec(3, 3)

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0:2, :], projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.coastlines(resolution='auto', color='k')
ax1.gridlines(color='lightgrey', linestyle='-', draw_labels=True)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[2, :])
ax2.plot([1, 2], [3, 4])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. This would work but it was not what I was looking for. fig.add_subplot is bit difficult to work under loops. I wanted an answer using plt.subplots. But this is not possible I guess, as already pointed out in comment previously.

Comment: `NameError: name 'ax' is not defined`

Comment: You are right @duff18, it should be
`ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())`
and not
`ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())`.
Fixed now.

Comment: can one adjust the distance between the subplots